# Title is removed/cleared/erased when starting editing

Tags: bug, revisions-list, title, editor, revision-redaction

First time this happens to me.

When I try to edit [I purchase api for sms gateway I have implmented in php. when i execute in localhost it shows error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826667/i-purchase-api-for-sms-gateway-i-have-implmented-in-php-when-i-execute-in-local), the title part is immediately erased:
[image]

And when I click cancel, the title becomes invisible:
[image]

---

Actually, the revision history is incomplete: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26826667/revisions

It shows that the question was asked *after* the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26826667/timeline

That's highly likely a result of an edition of the history by a moderator.

---

Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS 10.13.2 (17C88).

Comment: I guess that the original code in that question shown the values of `$pin` and `$uid`, which now are shown as `'obfuscated'`.