# Title disappearing when attempting to edit a question

Tags: bug, edits, title

1. I'm on that question: [Threading Isues With Fixed Thread Pool and Large Number of Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430595/threading-isues-with-fixed-thread-pool-and-large-number-of-tasks)
2. I tap "edit", and it brings me to that view, where Title field is empty:
   [image]
3. I tap "Cancel", and the title is gone:
   [image]
4. I refresh the page and the title is back.

I tried multiple times, but it only happens on that question.

Comment: I repro-ed that on Chrome/ WIn10 on a regular laptop (no touch).

Comment: @rene I also mean "click", sorry for the confusion, I wasn't on a touch screen either.

Comment: for some reason the call to `posts/26430595/edit-inline` doesn't produce any content in the  `<input id="title">`. Strange.

Comment: From [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26430595/revisions), looks like the original post (which contains the title) was redacted.

Comment: @NoDistractionWizard there is something off in the timeline as well: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26430595/timeline#history_0ceb0f24-b3b0-4c05-815e-d1a2b6c3310b as it has the wrong user.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304642/title-is-removed-cleared-erased-when-starting-editing) was a related bug report by you. And yeah, redaction seems quite buggy.

Comment: To be clear, it's not moderator redaction; it's the old staff-only revision deletion tool.

Comment: FTR, the two most recent events in the timeline are a flag by durron asking for redaction and an employee marking it helpful. Other than that, nothing suspicious there.

Comment: @Blue I had totally forgotten about that! Let's close it as duplicate. [edit: oh, I can't vote to close it as duplicate myself]

Comment: @Cœur Why can’t you vtc the post? Anyway, you should now be able to „accept“ the dupe vote using your OP rights.